# Android (MapView): How to set Zoom level of 4 miles in the mapview?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-mapview

I have a latitude and longitude(GeoPoint) which is the center of map.
I want to set zoom level of 4miles distance from latitude and longitude that I have.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the setzoom()-function to do so. The code below can be found in [this example](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android).

```
mc = mapView.getController();
String coordinates[] = {"1.352566007", "103.78921587"};
double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

p = new GeoPoint(
    (int) (lat * 1E6), 
    (int) (lng * 1E6));

mc.animateTo(p);
mc.setZoom(17);
```

Comment: Is there any documentation on Google Maps, relating zoom levels and distance.

Comment: I see in another comment of yours, you say you want to set it dynamically based on certain regions. Can you be a bit more specific? If I understand it correctly, you could obtain the coordinates of the map and use a switch-block to set the zoom levels. At some point you'll have to map zoom levels and regions anyway.

Comment: How you are saying that 4miles of distance corresponds to zoom level of 17?

Comment: Based on the user's preference have to zoom or pan.
To be more specific, have to zoom-in 4miles of distance from the corresponding geopoint which is the center point of the map.

Comment: The 17 was just a random value. I'm still entirely sure of what you mean, but I think this link can be help http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/6b1657a8477aa38a?pli=1 . It's not directly what you need, but it will help you get there. Also, here's a link to Google Maps and its scales between zoom level: http://michal.guerquin.com/googlemaps.html

Comment: this doesn't answer the question of relating miles to zoomlevel, and the links discuss the amount of pixels/sotrage needed for google maps, nothing to do with the user's question.

Answer (score 15):

SOLVED :

from Androd google API :
zoomlevel sets the zoomlevel of the map. The value will be clamped to be between 1 and 21 inclusive, though not all areas have tiles at higher zoom levels. This just sets the level of the zoom directly;
Parameters:
zoomLevel - At zoomLevel 1, the equator of the earth is 256 pixels long. Each successive zoom level is magnified by a factor of 2.
Returns:
the new zoom level, between 1 and 21 inclusive.

So 
given the Equator E = 40075 Km or 21.638,8 miles
given the distance to zoom D = 20 km or miles

the zoom level : L = log2(E/D)+1

This is the simple method I've used
remember to set E= 21.638,8 if you want to use the miles...

```
public static byte zoomLevel (double distance){
    byte zoom=1;
    double E = 40075;
    Log.i("Astrology", "result: "+ (Math.log(E/distance)/Math.log(2)+1));
    zoom = (byte) Math.round(Math.log(E/distance)/Math.log(2)+1);
    // to avoid exeptions
    if (zoom>21) zoom=21;
    if (zoom<1) zoom =1;

    return zoom;
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't account for the size of map view. On a bigger screen you see more terrain on the same zoom level. E.g., for the width of 512 pixels you need zoom level 2 to show the whole Earth, for 1024 (on a tablet) - zoom level 3, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Play with the `.setZoom(int);` parameter of your map. i think its around 15:

so `myMap.setZoom(15);`

Comment: I want to dynamically set the zoom level based on certain region. 
Is that possible?
I don't want to hard code "15"

Comment: Make a database with region / zoomlevel and read from that :-) You can use an SQlite database to store the data.

Comment: MapView doesn't have setZoom method.  MapController does.