# How can I determine zoom level of of that the demanded distance was visible?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, android-mapview

I have two points in my MapView. I Want select zoom level in MapController, that both  points would be visible in Map. How I can resolve this?

I find this question [Android (MapView): How to set Zoom level of 4 miles in the mapview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594855/android-mapview-how-to-set-zoom-level-of-4-miles-in-the-mapview)
But it doesn't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use com.google.android.maps.MapController.zoomToSpan for this kind of purpose.

Comment: Didn't think that the decision is such simple! Thank you very much!